# Sorting list alphabetically and by type

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, list, sorting

I have a list of instruments and I need to sort them to the following requirement.

order by:

1. cash
2. securities in alphabetical order
3. managed funds in alphabetical order

I have a list of instrument which has properties name and type, I've managed to sort alphabetically by name.

```
Instruments.Sort(Function(x, y) String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name))
Instruments.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name));
```

But I've been unable to come up with a graceful way of achieving the requirement.

Appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 you can use LINQ

```
var sorted = Instruments
    .OrderBy( x => x.Name )
    .ThenBy( x => x.Type );
```